# Почему синхронизированные коллекции, в синхронизированных методах, в этом примере - работают странно, для меня

Tags: java, многопоточность, коллекции, синхронизация, return

Почему, несмотря на синхронизацию, один раз - First Name выпадает раньше, а в другой раз - null. В одном из исходов сначала выводится null, а потом - First Name, как после удаления имени можно взять и вывести First Name? Объясните мне, как правильно прочитать этот код? Например, как срабатывает "return remove(0)"? Спасибо.

```
package synchronized_collections;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        NameList nameList = new NameList();
        nameList.addName("First Name");

        class MyThread extends Thread {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(nameList.removeFirstName() + "\nРазмер после удаления - " +  nameList.size());
            }

        }

        new MyThread().start(); 
        new MyThread().start();
    }

    static class NameList extends Thread {

        private List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()); 

        public synchronized void addName(String name) {
            list.add(name);
        }

        public synchronized String removeFirstName() { 

            if(list.size() > 0) { 
                return list.remove(0); 
            }

            System.out.println("----------------------------");

            return null;              
        }                         

        public synchronized int size() { 
            return list.size();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас синхронизированы методы внутри класса NameList, но в потоке MyThread, хоть там и одна строка кода, вы выполняете несколько различных операций:

```
System.out.println(nameList.removeFirstName() + "\nРазмер после удаления - " +  nameList.size());
```

Это равносильно вот такой записи:

```
String s1 = nameList.removeFirstName();
String s2 = nameList.size();
String s3 = s1 + "\nРазмер после удаления - " + nameList.size();
System.out.println(s3);
```

Как видите, это не атомарная операция, и не синхронизирована в один блок, так что между вызовами nameList.removeFirstName() и nameList.size() одного потока вполне может произойти какой-либо вызов из другого потока.

UPD. Для последовательного выполнения потоков нужно синхронизироваться на каком-нибудь общем для всех потоков объекте, например так:

```
public class Main extends Thread {

    private static Object obj = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        NameList nameList = new NameList();
        nameList.addName("First Name");

        class MyThread extends Thread {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (obj) {
                    System.out.println(nameList.removeFirstName() + "\nРазмер после удаления - " + nameList.size());
                }
            }

        }

        new MyThread().start();
        new MyThread().start();
    }

    static class NameList extends Thread {

        private List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

        public void addName(String name) {
            list.add(name);
        }

        public String removeFirstName() {
                if (list.size() > 0) {
                    return list.remove(0);
                }

                System.out.println("----------------------------");

                return null;
        }

        public int size() {
            return list.size();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Можете перечислить пару вариантов того, как может сработать программа? И как сделать так, чтобы работало предсказуемо. Как мне чёрт побери сделать, чтобы сначала вывелось First name, а потом - null, синхронизировать run() - не помогло, блок - тоже, использовать StringBuffer - тоже(Может я неправильно использовал). Спасибо.

Comment: @АльбертПетров дополнил ответ. Кроме этого примера, можно использовать класс Lock.

Comment: То есть, первый поток выходит из синхронизированного метода, может ему даже нужно зайти в другой синхронизированный метод, но в этот момент может вмешаться второй и зайти в него вместо первого? А про несинхронизированные методы вообще можно промолчать, так?

Comment: @АльбертПетров именно так. после того, как первый поток вышел из синхронизированного метода, нигде нет никаких блокировок и в этот момент все потоки равны, кому перепадет процессорное время, тот и будет исполняться следующим.